# Complete.ly Limiting Number of Results

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, complete.ly

Does anyone know how to limit the number of autocomplete suggestions when using complete.ly? I am going to be pulling choices from a database, and I do not want the page to be flooded with over-many results. Thanks. . .